Show that the subgroup of elements of odd order is normal and the order of the quotient is a power of $2$.
Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ generated by all elements of odd order. Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup, and the quotient $G/H$ has an order that is a power of $2$.
Don't know if this idea is right, but I think that $ghg^{-1}$ doesn't change the order of the element
$h$, because if its order is $n$, then for all $g\in G$ we got $(ghg^{-1})^n=gh^ng^{-1}=1$, but I’m not able to prove its the smallest number. If that's the case, then the first part about the normal subgroup is settled. How should we approach the second part?

Conjugation is an automorphism, so orders are preserved.  Also easy to prove by contradiction:  try it.

Also, pretty sure the statement as written is false.

what is false? i'll try to prove the first part

Your statement is likely true but not trivial

You should start by proving that elements of $K$ all have an order that is a power of $2$

Do you mean $H$ is generated by all elements (in $G$) of odd order? If $g \in G$ is an element of odd order, the subgroup $H = \langle g \rangle$ need not be normal.

See this question for $\pi={2}$.

We can see that the author of the question knows how to prove that H is a normal subgroup.
Let us prove that the order $|G/H|=2^n$ for some non-negative integer $n$.
For this purpose it suffices to notice that every element of $G/H$ is a $2$-element. Indeed, if $x\in G$, order $x$ is $m$, and $m=2^ks$, for some odd integer $s$, then $y=x^{2^k}$ is of order $s$.
Then $y\in H$ and therefore $(xH)^{2^k}=H$. As required.

As Randall said, conjugation is a group automorphism: $c_g: h \in G \to ghg^{-1}$ with inverse $c_{g^-1}$, hence it preserves order. Thus for any $g \in G$, $h \in H$, $o(ghg^{-1}) = o(h) = 1 \mod 2$, thus $gHg^{-1} = H$ and $H$ is normal.
Now consider the quotient $K = G/H$ we need to show that they are all elements which orders divides a power of $2$.
For $g \in G$ of even order, $v(g) := v_2 (o(g))$ (2-adic valuation) gives us that $g^{2^{v(g)}}$ is of order $o(g) / 2^{v(g)}$ which is odd, thus the order of $[g]$ in $K$ is $2^{v(g)}$.
We take $m = \max_{g \in G} v(g)$, we thus know that for every $g \in G$
$$[g]^{2^m} = [e].$$
Now this group has to be of order $2^k$ for a certain $k$. Let us suppose this is not the case; then $|K| = 2^l \cdot q$ where $2$ does not divide $q$ and $q \neq 1$. Thus there exists a prime $p \neq 2$ such that $p | q$ thus $p$ divides $|G|$.
Cauchy’s theorem, which is a consequence of Sylow’s theorem gives us that necessarily there is an element of order $p$ in $K$, which is absurd, thus $|G| = 2^k$ for a certain $k$.

+1 for explaining the key role of Cauchy's theorem.
